# Given a set of numbers, how to determine if variable x is significantly "in the middle" of the set?

Tags: statistics

I am working on an electronics project which requires some statistical analysis and I'm forgetting how to work this out.  I have a compass which determines (x,y) magnetic pull.  The problem is that the compass will return multiple values without moving at all.  My goal is to be able to confidently tell when the compass is pointing north when it's moving.

So I've pointed the compass north with a camping compass and recorded two hundred values of (x,y).  Now the question is, if the compass is rotating from south to north how can I determine if it is within the "range" that is accurately north?

So I need two things: 
First, how do I determine the statistically significant "middle" of a set?
Secondly, taking readings while the compass is rotating how can I be statistically confident that the compass is now pointing north accounting for the normal variability of the compass readings?

Comment: It's a good idea to divide the range of your random variable into equal discrete pieces and make a bar chart of the frequency with which you get readings within each segment. Ideally, the result looks kind of bell-shaped. If it doesn't, you may have to make some guesses about why not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say that when you point the compass north $(0^{\circ})$, the compass values have the distribution $X_{0^{\circ}}\sim F_{0^{\circ}}$. Hopefully, $E[X_{0^{\circ}}]=0^{\circ}$, otherwise, your compass is biased, so you will need to remove that first.

Once you have an unbiased $X_{0^{\circ}}$, you can begin to characterize the typical variability of the readings when it points north.

This can be set up as a hypothesis test of a population mean.

Let $X_o$ be the population of possible readings from the compass when it is pointing in some unknown direction. We can formulate the following hypothesis test:

$H_0:=E[X_o]=0$ vs. $H_a:=E[X_o]\neq 0$

Let the test statistic be the sample mean: $\bar X_n$, where $n$ is a pre-determined number of measurements.

The next step is to determine the *null distribution* of $\bar X_n$ when $H_0$ is true. We can do this nonparametrically by resampling from the values you got for $X_{0^{\circ}}$ (i.e., sample $n$ values from $X_{0^{\circ}}$ with replacement, calculate the sample mean, record the value, and repeat about 5000 times...the distribution of these values iks your [bootstrap null distribution](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35.htm)). I would check to see if this distribution is reasonably normal...if it is, then you can approximate the null distrbution using a Normal distribution with mean $0^{\circ}$ and standard deviation $\frac{s(X_{0^{\circ}})}{\sqrt{n}}$

Next, you need to determine your willingness to accept two types of errors:

1.The probability that you conclude it is not pointing north when it actually is (Type I). This probabiliy is called $\alpha$ 
 2.The probability that you conclude it is pointing north when it is actually not (Type II). This probability is called $\beta$

Related to the Type II error, you need to determine what range of directions around $0^{\circ}$ you are willing to accept as north (e.g., $350^{\circ} - 10^{\circ}$).

Once you answer the above questions, you are in a position to determine the correct value of $n$ and the *rejection region* $R_{\alpha,n}$ of $\bar X_n$ (which will simply be the upper and lower $\frac{\alpha}{2}$ of the distribution of $\bar X_n$:

You'll need to determine the sample size $n$ that will ensure that $P(\bar X_{n,0^{\circ}}-10^{\circ} \in R_{\alpha,n})\leq \beta$ and $P(\bar X_{n,0^{\circ}}+10^{\circ} \in R_{\alpha,n})\leq \beta$ so that you achieve the proper sensitivity and the associated $\alpha$-level rejection region.

Sorry for the long-winded answer, but I think if you take enough samples, you can rely on the normal approximation and then determine the sample size and rejection region using the [theory associated with the $Z-test$](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~bcaffo/651/files/hypothesisTestingReview.pdf).

Comment: Wow, that's awesome thank you. I guess I didn't realize how much I forgot about statistics. This sounds right but part of my problem is that I don't know the value of true north. My readings for north are around (670, -48). So I was assuming I would just take the mean value as north.

Comment: @binarylegit that is fine, as long as you realize that your test is now about whether the compass is pointing towards "nominal north" as defined by the mean of those measurements.